# Automation: Nexus docker container

Tags: nexus3

As part of automation, I can do the following configuration in Nexus custom docker file (which is extended from the Nexus image from DockerHub) . However I can not automate the Task creation and disable anonymous access.
Any help in this regard pls ?

```
nexus.scripts.allowCreation=true
nexus.security.randompassword=false
nexus.skipDefaultRepositories=true
```

And using Nexus CLI I can create the blob store, repository and cleanup policy.
I need to automate the Task creation and disable anonymous access.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am at the moment working on this particular problem.

You can see:
https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-scripting-examples as an example.

This project
https://github.com/dogukancagatay/nexus-automation

And don't forget that they want you to use the APIs instead of this script bases approach so you can do things like the API I'm working on that